# how to do incremental load processing in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Problem statement:-
we have tables in SQL Server like  tblTran,tblConditions,tblMatch and tblLoadStatus.

There is no common column between these tables
In both table news records will be inserted everyday and some records will be updated.

the tblTran will have more than 100 million records and new records will get inserted daily
tblConditions will have around 50000 records  and each day new records will get inserted or updated

tblConditions will have records something like that 
Condition1d         ConditionCol                                                                  INSERTED_DT     UPDATED_DT 
1                merchant in ('xyz',abc') and merchantcode='1001'
2                    merchantstate in ('HGI','OLT') 
3            customertype in ('xxx','yyy')           merchantstate in ('HGI','OLT')

what we are doing is we are running the condition against each and every tblTran table.

But this activity takes more then 4 to 5hrs. We plan to do this in spark by extracing the data from sql server and process it in spark.

Please suggest some ideas

History load:-

```
DECLARE condition_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT condition FROM tblConditions 
OPEN condition_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM condition_cursor INTO @condition
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
        query ='insert into tblMatch select * from tblTran where'+ condition<br>
        exe(query)
    FETCH NEXT FROM condition_cursor
INTO @condition
END 
CLOSE condition_cursor; 
DEALLOCATE condition_cursor;

insert into tblLoadStatus
select max(INSERTED_DT),'Completed' from tblConditions
```

---

Incremental load (when new rules gets inserted or existing rule gets updated we need to apply it on all the tblTran)

```
DECLARE @dt datetime 
SELECT @dt =  max(INSERTED_DT) FROM tblLoadStatus WHERE status = 'Completed' 

DECLARE condition_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT condition FROM tblConditions where INSERTED_DT > @dt and UPDATED_DT > @dt 
OPEN condition_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM condition_cursor INTO @condition 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN            
        query ='insert into tblMatch select * from tblTran where'+ condition 
        exe(query)
    FETCH NEXT FROM condition_cursor 
INTO @condition

END
CLOSE condition_cursor;
DEALLOCATE condition_cursor;

insert into tblLoadStatus
select max(INSERTED_DT),'Completed' from tblConditions
```

---

Incremental load (when new transaction get inserted into tblTran we need to rull all the conditions

```
DECLARE condition_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT condition FROM tblConditions 
OPEN condition_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM condition_cursor INTO @condition
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN       
        query ='insert into tblMatch select * from tblTran where'+ condition
        exe(query)
    FETCH NEXT FROM condition_cursor
INTO @condition

END
CLOSE condition_cursor;
DEALLOCATE condition_cursor;

insert into tblLoadStatus
select max(INSERTED_DT),'Completed' from tblConditions
```

Comment: can you format a bit `tblConditions`?

Comment: `Please suggest some ideas` is opinion based. Pls update your question so we can answer with facts, not opinions ...